# AChartEngine display value not to be shown when its value = 0

Tags: android, achartengine

I am working on Pie charts using AChartEngine library. Here I want to disable chart values to show on charts, but only those whose content value is 0.

Now I am using it like:

```
         public Intent execute_assetLifecycle(Context context,RelativeLayout parent) {
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.RED, Color.DKGRAY, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN,Color.GREEN,Color.GRAY };
    DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);

    CategorySeries categorySeries = new CategorySeries("Title1");


        categorySeries.add("30 Days=" days_count_30);  

        categorySeries.add("60 Days=", days_count_60);

        categorySeries.add("90 Days=", days_count_90);

        categorySeries.add("180 Days=", days_count_180);


    mChartView2=ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, categorySeries,renderer);

    parent.addView(mChartView2);
    return ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(context, categorySeries, renderer,null);
    }

    protected DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(int[] colors) {
    DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
    for (int color : colors) {
    SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(color);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

    }
    return renderer;
    }
```

I am using the above code to display pie chart with display values, but I want to show only those display values which are >0 otherwise They will not be shown on the charts as label like: **30 days=0**

Please suggest any method that would stop displaying chart values when its value ==0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an If-statement to check in the value is zero before adding the series.
Maybe make your own wrapper-function for the `categorySeries.add` like thus:

```
private void add(String category,double value){
    if(value != 0){
        categorySeries.add(category,value);
    }
}
```

You might have to limit the number of renderes to the number of actually added series.